# sDNA License Manager says Please wait?

Tags: installation, license, sdna

I installed sDNA and got my license, now I'm trying to runthe sDNA License Manager. I entered the code in the field to get the Challenge URL but the status information still says:

> Please wait...

I've waited now for almost three hours.

Does it normally take so long or is there something wrong?

Comment: No, this shouldn't take a moment (it's a fully offline process). Most likely it has stalled for some reason trying to determine your mac address and serial number for a hardware fingerprint. What is your windows version? Have you tried running sdna license manager as administrator?